# Is pl/pgsql debugging broken in PostgreSQL 9.0, or is it just me?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I had the debugger working in pgAdminIII at one point, some time before upgrading to 9.0, but as of right now I can't seem to get it working using [the usual steps](http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/1809.page).  I believe it may have something to do with the DLL not loading correctly, because the following query:

```
LOAD '$libdir/plugins/plugin_debugger.dll';
show shared_preload_libraries;
```

...returns a blank row.  The DLL is present, and if I change the load string, it complains, so I'm pretty sure it's finding the DLL okay, but not successfully loading it.  `show local_preload_libraries` returns the same thing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just me.  I had been carelessly selecting non-`plpgsql` functions the whole time.  Of course, the aptly-named debugger does not operate on `SQL` or `plperl` functions...

Boy is my face red.[/dilbertquote]

Comment: Also, don't follow my `LOAD` code above, but follow the cited usual steps wherein you modify the config file and restart.